# Using function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
function pcs()
{
    var t1 = document.getElementById("tot1").value
    var pb = document.getElementById("pcbox").value
    var pc = ""

    if (t1==! && pb==!)
    {
        document.getElementId("rbox").innerHTML = ""
    }
}
```

My question is if `t1` and `pb` are null the function `pcs()` is not called... Why?

Comment: Please Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469150/im-new-to-stackoverflow-what-should-i-consider-before-asking-questions

Comment: Be nice with him. Think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
if(t1==! && pb==!)
```

is not legal syntax.  If this is exactly how you have written the code it will not parse and thus the function will not be defined (plus you'll be getting Javascript errors).

Perhaps you meant

```
if(t1 != null && pb != null)
```

Additionally, while semicolons at the end of lines can be inferred by the interpreter, they are *meant* to be there (as opposed to being actually optional) and adding them is good practice.

**EDIT** and while I didn't understand your final question 100%, remember that the code you've written (assuming the syntax were correct) merely *defines* a function.  You will need to have some other code call this function at an appropriate point in order to have it executed, e.g. for some element `onblur = pcs();`

Answer (score 3):

The line `if(t1==! && pb==!)` is nonsense - did you mean `if (!t1 && !pb)`?

Answer (score 2):

`if(t1==! && pb==!)` --> this is absolutly wrong.... What are you trying to check?

Maybe `if(t1!="" && pb!="")`?